# iOS screenshot with cordova is not in the photos library

Tags: ios, cordova, screenshot

I'm using the cordova screenshot plugin  : https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot to take a screenshot in my iPhone using this code :

```
navigator.screenshot.save(function (error, res) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Screenshot error');
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                console.log('screenshot ok', res.filePath);
            }
        }, 'jpg', 50, 'project-X-result');
```

It seems to work (i have no error) but I can't find the screenshot in the Photos Library. Is it possible to save it in this library?

How should I do? Using another plugin to move the file? (where should it be moved exactly?) Editing the plugin to save it directly in the library? (where should it be saved exactly?)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran through the same problem. It took several days but I figured out how to do it.

It does involve another plugin Canvas2Image plugin. I didn't think it would work, but I was desperate and it did work in the end. Here's how I did it.

If you are getting the console.log for screenshot ok, then you are in good shape. The next thing you will need to do is install Canvas2Image with your CLI like so:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin.git
```

(or replace 'cordova' with 'phonegap' if you use that instead.)

Next, you will need to add a function (in this case saveImageToPhone()) that calls the plugin you just added to your project. This function will be called from your navigator.screenshot.save() function you already have. We will add that function call to your screenshot.save success block, right after the console.log line.

The key here is using that filePath property that we get back in the success block; That's our absolute path to the image we just saved to the temp folder in iOS. We will simply pass that path to the second function and let it do its work.

Here's those two functions from my code:

```
function saveScreen(){
    navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res){
          if(error){
            console.error(error);
          }else{
            console.log('ok',res.filePath);

            var MEsuccess = function(msg){
            console.info(msg);
            }   ;

            var MEerror = function(err){
                console.error(err);
            };

            saveImageToPhone(res.filePath, MEsuccess, MEerror);
          }
        },'jpg',90);
}

function saveImageToPhone(url, success, error) {
    var canvas, context, imageDataUrl, imageData;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        try {
            imageDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
            imageData = imageDataUrl.replace(/data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, '');
            cordova.exec(
                success,
                error,
                'Canvas2ImagePlugin',
                'saveImageDataToLibrary',
                [imageData]
            );
        }
        catch(e) {
            error(e.message);
        }
    };
    try {
        img.src = url;
    }
    catch(e) {
        error(e.message);
    }
}
```

Now just call the first function from wherever you wish.
If it works, you'll get a console.log right after your filePath readout that says

```
IMAGE SAVED!
```

Be careful, you might overwrite the same screenshot if you use a name as a screenshot.save parameter (after your jpg and quality parameters). My app needs to save different screenshots and have them all available later; by removing the name parameter and allowing the OS to name the file I was able to achieve just that.

I hope that helps you out, I know it caused me a lot of trouble...

Comment: Thanks for help but Image is saved but not scaled image